# Pgfplots: changing plot size breaks color map

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This small plot compiles as expected with a colorbar on the side:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},colorbar, colormap/RdGy-11]
    \addplot3 [surf] {x*y};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example 1]

However, if I try to scale the plot by adding `small` to the axis:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[small,view={0}{90},colorbar, colormap/RdGy-11]
    \addplot3 [surf] {x*y};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There's this little annoying glitch at the top of the colorbar:

[image: Example 2]

I ran into this example in a much more involved example, and it took me hours to rule out other things to figure out that scaling caused the issue. Some color maps do and don't cause this issue. This also happens if I do `width=...,height=...` instead of `small`. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: This works as expected for me. Are you sure this is not a (PDF) viewer issue? If yes, which version of TikZ and PGFPlots are you using? I am using TikZ v3.1.3 and PGFPlots v1.16.

Comment: I confirm @StefanPinnow's observations, regardless of whether I use the current version (1.16) or run it in the backward compatibility mode, and regardless of whether I use `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The result is fine under preview or acroread.

Comment: The screenshots are taken from Overleaf (no special setup), and I had the same issue on my local computer. I had this issue on pgfplots v1.15 and tikz v3.01a on overleaf

Comment: So I guess the simple answer is: Update the packages ... I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because updating TikZ and PGFPlots most likely will solve the problem.

Comment: IMHO this is something for the overleaf support.

Comment: On my local computer pgfplots is version v1.16 and tikz is v3.0.1a as well and I'm having the same problem. Let me try using a different pdf viewer

Answer (score 1):

This is a pdf viewer problem. PDF.js on Firefox, and in VSCode inline viewer which I'd been using, shows this incorrectly, while using other PDF viewers show the correct gradient there. It's worth pointing out that the version of PGFPlots and Tikz used does not affect the problem, the versions I've tried all cause the problem.

Whatever the pdf problem is, it's probably not a LaTeX issue. Thanks for the suggestions in the comments!

FAST UPDATE: A bug has been filed with PDF.js [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10874) for future reference